# Is ‘i will arrive at 1:45’ a correct sentence? Can we use arrive with ‘i’ and ‘time’?

Tags: grammar

I m confused..!! Can someone please help me? I coudn’ find the answer even on the net.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "I will arrive at 1:45" sounds correct for me. It is okay to use the verb "arrive" in such case.